# Nibblonians with DOOP

Tags: futurama

Nibblionians were a race who matured before the Big Bang.  They made themselves protectors against the evil brain spawn.  After the brain spawn were sent to another dimension, the Nibblonians no longer had an enemy.

As we see, the Nibblonians are a sentient mysterious race.  So why haven't the Nibblonians join DOOP to reveal their existence?  Is it because they are too cute?

Answer (score 1):

Doop has such promising members as Zap Brannigan, and their headquarters has a giant laser attached to it.

I don't think the Nibblonians would want or need to associate with such immature and violent people.